# How to create a custom field for a file upload, and make it private

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, files, filesystem

We would like to create a custom field in CiviCRM for a file upload, and link it to the CiviCRM Webforms Integration module while at the same time keeping it "private" and is not publicly accessible.

Is there a way to do this in CiviCRM? Or maybe this is a default behaviour and files uploaded to CiviCRM are kept private? (Not accessible from the web directly etc..).

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CiviCRM files are never directly web-accessible. If you are also using Webform integration to submit the file, then a copy of the file is also stored in Drupal. You could either make your Drupal files private (this is a Drupal setting) or you could implement a hook to delete the files from Drupal after they are uploaded.